# ¿Cómo añadir filas a un ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de una agenda. A la hora de mostrar la lista de la agenda solo se muestra una fila en el listview, pero los datos se recogen de la base de datos y se meten en el array que posteriormente paso al arrayadpter. No se si influirá o no, pero no estoy cargandolos en el activity, sino en un fragment del activity.
Perdonad si no soy especifica con la pregunta, pero estoy empezando con Android y sigo bastante verde y sin saber por donde coger algunas cosas.

Os dejo el **código del fragment**:

```
public class listContactos extends android.app.Fragment {
    View fragmento;
    ListView lista_clientes;
    ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;
    ArrayList<String> info_clientes;
    ConexionSQLiteHelper conexion;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;

    public listContactos() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        fragmento = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_contacto, container, false);

        addViews();

        return fragmento;
    }


    public void addViews()  {
        lista_clientes = fragmento.findViewById(R.id.lista_clientes);

        recogerClientes();

        adaptador = new ArrayAdapter <>(getActivity() , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , info_clientes);
        lista_clientes.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }

    public void recogerClientes()
    {

        conexion = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext() , "db_clientes" , null , 1);

        SQLiteDatabase db = conexion.getReadableDatabase();

        Cliente cliente = null;
        clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Constantes.TABLA_CLIENTES , null);

        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            cliente = new Cliente();

            cliente.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            cliente.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));
            cliente.setTelefono(cursor.getString(2));



            clientes.add(cliente);
            System.out.println(clientes.size());
        }

        cursor.close();
        conexion.close();
        establecerLista();
    }

    private void establecerLista()
    {
        info_clientes = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0; i<clientes.size(); i++)
        {
            info_clientes.add(
                            "Id : " + clientes.get(i).getId() + " - " +
                            "Nombre: " + clientes.get(i).getNombre() + " - " +
                            "Telefono: " + clientes.get(i).getTelefono()
                            );

            System.out.println("inf: " + info_clientes.size());
        }

        for(String c: info_clientes){
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }


}
```

Y este es el xml donde tengo la parte de diseño del **layout que uso en el fragment**. Es tan solo un ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.listContactos">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista_clientes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Cualquier cosa que me pidáis edito, gracias de antemano ^^

Comment: Que te muestran los system.out.println()? Aparte un par de comentarios: Me parece que deberia ser ArrayAdapter<String>, y el armado de la lista de datos (recogerClientes()), lo llamaría en onCreate() en lugar de onCreateView().

Comment: Buenas Juan, gracias por la recomendación, pero no ha habido suerte. he colocado los dos cambios que me has mencionado y nada. Los system.out.print me devuelven todos los datos que tengo almacenados y son introducidos en el array que le paso al adpater, lo he comprobado, por eso no termino de entener el porque no funciona

Comment: Corrí tu código (sin la parte de base de datos), y veo que funciona bien. Podes agregar el layout del fragment? Por ahi tenés algo mal dimensionado ahí.

Comment: Editado, ahi te lo he dejado. Aunque tan solo tengo un ListView ^^"

Comment: Este layout como encaja en el main Activity? Es decir, al listview lo ves ocupando toda la pantalla y mostrando solo un registro? O puede ser que el listview solo este ocupando un parte de la pantalla que le deja mostrar solo un registro?

Comment: Eureka, era eso ^^ le he puesto un tamaño fijo al ListView y si que se muestran los registros, lo que no entiendo es el porque ni con match_parent ni con wrap_content se adapta al resultado